# Is it possible to deny direct usage of javascript properties in typescript?

Tags: typescript, kendo-ui

We often have have objects extending kendo.data.ObservableObject .

It's possible to define/override 'get' and 'set' to have stricter types, ensuring that the key exists on the property before using set or get (therefore getting type information on what you get back).

```
get<T extends ObservableObject, K extends keyof T>(this: T, name: K): T[K];
set<T extends ObservableObject, K extends keyof T>(this: T, name: K, value: T[K]): void;
```

However, if anything is relying on the dynamic nature of get/set, it will result in an error, good or bad depending on context.

set will cause an event to be emitted by kendo, to update any subscribers to the observable object.

However, people are in the habit of setting them directly, using

```
class X extends ObservableObject { s:string = "";}

X.s = "set a string";
```

Which (to my knowledge) will intentionally **not** emit an event.

However, using the direct backing variable is a habit that is hard to break.

Is it possible using Typescript, to create a type/class that makes it impossible to set the values directly? instead relying upon a `setNoEmit` method instead? that way, it's no longer possible for junior developers to make the mistake of updating the observable, without firing the event, and have to make a conscious decision between `set` and `setNoEmit` ?

Making the variables readonly may work, but ultimately mislead the compiler about their types.

Comment: Direct assignments have their place for observables, starting with the constructor: `this._events = {}`.  You might need them in some future scenarios. Also, there are reasons to use set over assignment, and I'm worried that your colleagues don't see those reasons. I believe it should come up when someone tests their code.

Comment: I mean this is Javascript... Just completely re-declare the concrete class and make some stuff private?

Comment: @Galois sure, your points are all valid, I'd just prefer it to be explicit, rather then by accident. It's also mostly code that is already that way, and changing the inheritance to force the issue would make a handy list of errors in the compiler.

Comment: @ZZe that may not work, because when binding some observables, Kendo checks whether they're instances of kendo.data.Observable[Array] and wraps them in those types if they're not.